# Script on Linux only gives me "no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've come across a problem, I am writing a script that would find the biggest file in directory and sub-directories, then show full path on screen. Can't seem to get it working.
The error I'm getting is "bash: scriptas.sh: No such file or directory"
There are two .mp3 files in the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
du -a /dir/ | sort -n -r | head -n 1
echo pwd
```

I am totally new to this.

Comment: That script should work as it is (assuming `/dir/` exists). Please provide the complete script, the actual error message (not your interpretation of it) and the output of an `ls` showing that the dir exists.

Comment: is `scriptas.sh` the name of your script? If yes, and it is in your current directory, run it as `./scriptas.sh`. And make sure it's executable.

Comment: Could you explain a bit in more in depth about what you just said? Yes, its the name of the script. It's in the directory that I am at the moment. Couldn't understand the last two parts.

Comment: The directory where you currently are is by default not in the system path. If you want to execute a script named `scriptas.sh` that is in your current directory you have to type `./scriptas.sh`. And for that it has to be executable (`chmod +x scriptas.sh`).

Answer (score 2):

Like Gerald says in his comment, I think you must set a ./ to execute your script.
However, i think your script will return you the folder and not the file.

Personally, i would have used find :

```
find /dir/ -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -1
```

Comment: Nice, but you should write `head -n 1` instead of `head -1`, which is obsolete syntax

Comment: yep, you 're right.

Comment: Could you explain to me what -printf '%s %p\n' means/does ?

Comment: %s File's size in bytes.

    %p File's name.